# How can I use sklearn's GridSearchCV with data that doesn't fit in memory?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bigdata, grid-search

I have a dataset that is much too large to fit in memory, so I must train models in batches. I have wrapped my model in a GridSearchCV, a RandomizedSearchCV, or a BayesSearchCV (from scikit-optimize) and see I can not train multiple instances of these on different parts of my enormous dataset and expect the best hyperparameters found by each will agree.

I have considered wrapping my estimators in a BatchVoter (of my own design) that manages reading from the database in batches and keeps a list of models. Passing this to the XSeachCV and updating the parameter space dictionary so all keys lead with 'estimator__' might direct the the search to set the parameters of the sub-object, but there is still a problem: A search is begun with a call to the .fit() method, which must take data.

*Is there a clever way to use the native GridSearchCV with data that is too big to pass to the .fit() method?*

Answer (score 1):

Try [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/). It supports Data Frames, arrays and collections. It consists of a scheduler and workers. It also has a [distributed](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) scheduler, allowing to process data frames on several PCs.

[Here](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2016/07/12/dask-learn-part-1) is the description on how to parallelize models.

[Here](http://dask-searchcv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the link to a complete module, that could be a drop-in replacement of `GridSearchCV`

Comment: I can't use any different packages without delaying this project significantly. New packages have to be approved, and then I'll have to refactor everything on top of my new design. Our database is based on numpy memmaps, which are insanely fast and work well for us, and dask does not do Bayesian optimization, which is kind of the whole point I'm refactoring now. Distributing to multiple cores is good enough for now, and n_jobs=X does this easily. But I'll keep dask in mind for future work.

Comment: I'm not even sure dask could solve the fundamental batching problem: If a learner needs to see all the data at once to learn, then it either all needs to fit on memory somewhere or I'll have to cause a ton of page faults looking around at a memory-mapped file on disk, which will be slow. In my problem, we actually do a join of a couple of the database tables at read-time, so the hundred GB on disk explodes to TB for training.